# Missing elements from web-fragment.xml in the effective web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat

In our project we make use of web-fragments to define some servlets so the artifacts easily can be used in other projects.

Strange thing now is that we have a web-fragment.xml, but some of its contents doesn't get added to the effective web.xml.

By example:

The following configurations is present in the effective web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>superUserAutomaticLogon</filter-name>
    <filter-class>nl.caiw.cool.util.filters.SuperUserAutomaticLogonFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</filter>
```

But the following isn't:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/toolbox/modules/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

We have tried several things, but we can't figure it out. Hopefully someone here can send us  in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are your fragments located? What does the document element of your `web.xml` file look like? What version of Tomcat are you running?

Answer (score 14):

> Strange thing now is that we have a web-fragment.xml, but some of its contents doesn't get added to the effective web.xml.

Well first of all, a `web-fragment.xml` wouldn't get *physically* included into the main `web.xml`. So when you say it doesn't get added to the effective `web.xml`, I feel you may be going wrong there.

Web fragments allow compoments to register themselves to the main `web.xml` at runtime. The only evidence you will find of this happening is by actually trying to use the compoment.

I tried out a simple hello-world example with web fragments and got it to work. I used Tomcat 7 for this with a Servlet 3.0 webapp.

My main `web.xml` inside `WEB-INF` looks like the below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>hello-world</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering>
        <name>filters</name>
    </absolute-ordering>
</web-app>
```

I figured out that the only way we could register a `web-fragment.xml` was by adhering to the below rules:

1. It must be named `web-fragment.xml`
2. It must be placed in a JAR file inside `WEB-INF/lib`
3. The `web-fragment.xml` must be present inside the `META-INF` directory of the JAR file.

My `web-fragment.xml` looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-fragment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd" id="WebAppFragment_ID" version="3.0">
    <name>filters</name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>interceptor</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.adarshr.Interceptor</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>interceptor</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-fragment>
```

With the above minimal setup, I was able to get the `Interceptor` filter to get fired, though it was placed in the `web-fragment.xml`.

Finally, here is my directory structure (generated using http://www.adarshr.com/treegen)

```
+- hello-world
   |
   +- WEB-INF
       |
       +- lib
       |   |
       |   |- my-library.jar
       |
       |- web.xml
```

The JAR file `my-library.jar` has the below structure:

```
+- my-library.jar
   |
   +- META-INF
       |
       |- web-fragment.xml
```

Some references:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment
- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part2.html

Comment: We have all that, but strange thing is that some of the filters doesn't work and some do. So the web-fragment.xml will be used and registers it into the web.xml, but for some unknown reason some valid declarations won't. If we place the missing  declaration in the web.xml it works like a charm. Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: Are you sure your changes are getting actually deployed and that you're not running some stale version of `web-fragment.xml`? Try cleaning the temp and work directories of your container.

Comment: We are sure. Also tried it on several environments and they have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can check on `web.xml` that `metadata-complete="true"` is not set. According to the Servlet spec if this flag is set to true, it will not load `web-fragment.xml` or any annotation such as `@WebFilter`

Comment: Pointer to where this is mentioned in the spec would be a nice to include in the answer.

Comment: @dade Here is the `servlet 3.0 spec`(`jsr 315`) where it defines how metadata-complete attribute on web-app element should be used. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-full-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-mrel-spec.pdf#page=26

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were running into what I explained in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248491/can-i-refer-a-servlet-or-filter-in-web-xml-from-web-fragment-xml/73422964#73422964).

servet-mappings with the same servlet-name and filter-mappings with the same filter-name occurring in web-fragments are overridden by those in web.xml. They are only additive *across* web-fragments.