# Can I refer a servlet or filter in web.xml from web-fragment.xml?

Tags: servlets, filter

So I have a web.xml that defines a servlet or a filter that has some servlet-mapping or filter-mapping associated with it, then I want to add some more servlet-mapping/filter-mapping entries in web-fragment.xml, will that work?
Say web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>A</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.A</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>A</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Path1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then in web-fragment.xml I have

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>A</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Path2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

From my testing it doesn't work but I don't understand why would it be so.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I seem to seeing the same behavior, of filter-mappings and servlet-mappings not being pulled in from the web-fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same issue. I believe the answer is that he [3.1 servlet spec](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf)  says

> <servlet-mapping> elements with the same <servlet-name> are additive
> across web-fragments. <servlet-mapping> specified in the web.xml
> overrides values specified in the web-fragments with the same
> <servlet-name>

(And something analogous for filter-mappings.)

They are additive *only across web-fragments*, not *across both the web.xml and the web-fragments*. If they occur in the web.xml, they override all the ones on the fragments. This seemed to be born out by my testing with Tomcat using the logEffectiveWebXml feature.

So you *could* make this work by moving these mapping out of the web.xml into a web-fragment.xml. (In my a case, I decided to abandon the web-fragments approach as it became too hard to manage the ordering across multiple files.)

Answer (score -1):

As of [Servlet 3.0 Specification](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment) web-fragment is introduced for for pluggability of library jars which are packaged under WEB-INF/lib. The content of web.xml and web-fragment.xml are almost the same.

I guess you are not linking your fragments to web.xml, so probably you have to do something like this:

```
 <absolute-ordering>
    <name>fragment3</name>
    <name>fragment2</name>
    <name>fragment1</name>
    <others/>
    ...
</absolute-ordering>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure the web-fragment.xml is linked to the web.xml, since there are some other new filter/servlet defined in the web-fragment.xml and I can see that they're created. The only problem is that the servlet-mapping in question doesn't get added to the ones in web.xml, although by the Servlet 3.0 Specification, "servlet-mapping elements are additive".